# Command Line Arg in VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

command line arguments having null after each char suppose i call the program from the command prompt like "abc.exe test data" then in memory there is an space after each char and the data is "t.e.s.t..d.a.t.a" What is the issue.
It is printing t only the first char not the complete string "test"
What is the issue.
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("The number of Argc %d  %s",argc,argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

You are using UNICODE encoding (see the `_t` prefix in `_tmain` and `_tchar`).
This encoding stores characters on 2 bytes.

Hence you should use `_tprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: If you insist on using printf() you can use the %S format specifier to output WCHARs. The correct way is what @Heandel said.